# Derivation of a "triangulation theorem" of a cubic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

$A$ is a cubic matrix which has eigenvalues $~\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ which are assumed to be pairwise distinct.

I want to prove the following proposition.

$$
\exists~\text{invertible}~P~\textit{s.t.}~P^{-1}AP=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&*&*\\0&\lambda_2&*\\0&0&\lambda_3\end{bmatrix}
$$

The critical parts of my post are painted with red and blue at far below.

$$
B:=P^{-1}AP=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&*&*\\0&\lambda_2&*\\0&0&\lambda_3\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
P:=\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{x}_{1}~\boldsymbol{x}_{2}~\boldsymbol{x}_{3}\end{bmatrix}~\textit{s.t.}~AP=PB
$$

We'll focus on condition(s) which$~\boldsymbol{x}_{1}~$should satisfy.

$$\begin{align}
AP&=A\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{x}_{1}~\boldsymbol{x}_{2}~\boldsymbol{x}_{3}\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}A\boldsymbol{x}_{1}~A\boldsymbol{x}_{2}~A\boldsymbol{x}_{3}\end{bmatrix}\\
PB&=\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{x}_{1}~\boldsymbol{x}_{2}~\boldsymbol{x}_{3}\end{bmatrix}B\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{x}_{1}~\boldsymbol{x}_{2}~\boldsymbol{x}_{3}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&*&*\\0&\lambda_2&*\\0&0&\lambda_3\end{bmatrix}\\&=
\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1\boldsymbol{x}_{1}&*&*\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$

Hence$~A\boldsymbol{x}_{1}=\lambda_1\boldsymbol{x}_{1}~$should be satisfied. Namely this$~\boldsymbol{x}_{1}~$is an eigenvector of$~A~$

Here I haven't proven that as eigenvalue of square matrix is determined then absosultely there exists non-zero corresponding eigenvectors but I ignore proving it.

And we choose$~\boldsymbol{x}_{2},\boldsymbol{x}_{3}~$such that$~\underbrace{P_1=\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{x}_{1}~\boldsymbol{x}_{2}~\boldsymbol{x}_{3}\end{bmatrix}}_{\text{Newly defined on the book}}~$is invertible. I assume$~\boldsymbol{x}_{2},\boldsymbol{x}_{3}~$are eigenvectors corresponding to$~\lambda_2,\lambda_3~$respectively.

$$\begin{align}
P_{1}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{y}_{1}\\\boldsymbol{y}_{2}\\\boldsymbol{y}_{3}\end{bmatrix}\leftrightsquigarrow\text{Representation using row vectors}
\end{align}$$

$$P_{1}^{-1}P_1=I=\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{y}_{1}\\\boldsymbol{y}_{2}\\\boldsymbol{y}_{3}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{x}_{1}~\boldsymbol{x}_{2}~\boldsymbol{x}_{3}\end{bmatrix}\leftrightsquigarrow
\begin{cases}
\boldsymbol{y}_{1}\boldsymbol{x}_{1}=1\\
\boldsymbol{y}_{2}\boldsymbol{x}_{1}=0\\
\boldsymbol{y}_{3}\boldsymbol{x}_{1}=0\\
\end{cases}\tag{1}
$$

$$\begin{align}
P_1^{-1}AP_1&=\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{y}_{1}\\\boldsymbol{y}_{2}\\\boldsymbol{y}_{3}\end{bmatrix}A\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{x}_{1}~\boldsymbol{x}_{2}~\boldsymbol{x}_{3}\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{y}_{1}\\\boldsymbol{y}_{2}\\\boldsymbol{y}_{3}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1\boldsymbol{x}_{1}&*&*\end{bmatrix}\\&=
\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&\begin{matrix}*&*\end{matrix}\\
\boldsymbol{0}_{}&A_2\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$

Since$~\varphi_A(t)=\varphi_{P_1^{-1}AP_1}(t)=(\lambda_1-t)\varphi_{A_2}(t)~$is held, eigenvalues of$~A_2~$are$~\lambda_2,\lambda_3~$

$$\begin{align}
P_2&:=\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{x}_{2}'&\boldsymbol{x}_{3}'\end{bmatrix}\leftrightsquigarrow~\text{eigenvectors corresponding to}~\lambda_2,\lambda_3
\end{align}$$

Doing operations against$~P_2~$likewise we did previously, I got the follwing.

$$P_2^{-1}A_2 P_2=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_2&*\\0&\lambda_3\end{bmatrix}\tag{2}$$

$$
\underbrace{
\color{red}{P=P_1\begin{bmatrix}1&\begin{matrix}0&0\end{matrix}\\\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}&P_2\end{bmatrix}\implies P^{-1}AP=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&*&*\\0&\lambda_2&*\\0&0&\lambda_3\end{bmatrix}}}_{\text{Final problem which I have to understand}}
$$

To analyze the above equations, I will use the following general formula.

*As $~ A ~$ and $~ B ~$ are invertible, then $~ (AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1} ~$*

So $~ P_1 ~$ is invertible and the right matrix which is multipled by $~ P_1 ~$ is also invertible hence $~ P ~$ is invertible.

$$\begin{align}
P^{-1}AP&=\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&\begin{matrix}0&0\end{matrix}\\\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}&P_2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}P_1^{-1} \right)A \left(P_1\begin{bmatrix}1&\begin{matrix}0&0\end{matrix}\\\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}&P_2\end{bmatrix} \right)\\&=\underbrace{\color{blue}{\begin{bmatrix}1&\begin{matrix}0&0\end{matrix}\\\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}&P_2^{-1}\end{bmatrix}P_1^{-1}AP_1\begin{bmatrix}1&\begin{matrix}0&0\end{matrix}\\\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}&P_2\end{bmatrix}}  }_{\text{I've been stucked from here} } 
\end{align}$$

Comment: I even got more progress which is derived just reffering my written eqn.

Comment: I am doing a work so will add my progress later.

Answer (score 1):

Just proceed the calculations. ***I should have used a conception of multiplications between submatrices.***

$$\begin{align}
P^{-1}AP&=
\begin{bmatrix}1&\begin{matrix}0&0\end{matrix}\\\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}&P_2^{-1}\end{bmatrix}P_1^{-1}AP_1\begin{bmatrix}1&\begin{matrix}0&0\end{matrix}\\\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}&P_2\end{bmatrix}\\&=
\begin{bmatrix}1&\begin{matrix}0&0\end{matrix}\\\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}&P_2^{-1}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&\begin{matrix}*&*\end{matrix}\\
\boldsymbol{0}_{}&A_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&\begin{matrix}0&0\end{matrix}\\\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}&P_2\end{bmatrix}\\&=\cdots\\&=
\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1 & \begin{matrix} * & *\end{matrix}  \\ \begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix} & P_2^{-1} A_2P_2\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

For $i=1,2,3$ let $v_i$ be an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\lambda _i$. Let $P$ be the 3x3 matrix whose $i-$th column is $v_i$ for $i=1,2,3$. Then $P$ is invertible and $AP=P  $diag($\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$).